# Ant script fails to run PHPUnit tests in Windows

Tags: php, windows, ant, phpunit

I am using windows environment , I have setup `phpunit`

in **C:/users/kanishka/Desktop/php_unit** folder i have two php files

**User.php**

```
class User {
    protected $name;

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function talk() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

**UserTest.php**

```
<?php
require_once "PHPUnit/Autoload.php";
require_once "User.php";

class UserTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  protected $user;

    protected function setUp() {
        $this->user = new User();
        $this->user->setName("Tom");
    }

    public function testTalk() {
        $expected = "Hello world!";
        $actual = $this->user->talk();
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
        unset($this->user);
    }   

}
```

when i type **phpunit UnitTest UserTest.php**

> PHPUnit 3.6.3 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> .
>
> Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.75Mb
>
> OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Now I am trying to run this test automatically via **ant**

I have ant build.xml file in **C:/users/kanishka/Desktop**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="phpunit">

<target name="phpunit">

<exec executable="phpunit" failonerror="true">

    <arg value="php_unit/UserTest.php" />   

</exec>

</target>
</project>
```

I am trying to run **UserTest.php**

but I am getting this error

[image]

so ant file can not detect the path :( . please help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

my problem was i havent put the correct values for <**exec executable**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="test" default="phpunit2" basedir="." >

<property name="phpunit.path" location="D:\xampp\php"/>

<target name="phpunit2">
    <exec executable="${phpunit.path}/phpunit.bat" dir=".">
        <arg path="php_unit/UserTest.php" />
    </exec>
</target>

</project>
```

now it is working :)

I got the idea from this question

[Ant can't find a executable in the Windows path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088470/ant-cant-find-a-executable-in-the-windows-path)